# How to use predefined css classes from Vue.js libraries?

Tags: css, vue.js, charts

I work with CSS rarely, but I really want to style my chart. The chart is from a vue.js library and has predefined CSS classes. I just don't know how I am able to access them.

**HTML:**
[image: HTML]

**CSS:**

[image: CSS]

This is how the document describes the use of CSS with the library:
[image: document]

Comment: Please use code formatting instead of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get the full picture only from the images you shared. But it should be relatively easy to just override the default styles that the library uses. If you know what the class names are.

For example:

```html
<style scoped>
year: {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [scoped styles docs](https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html).

What you need is a "deep" selector.

So if you want to override child component's styles your css should look like

```css
.vtc-statistik /deep/ .vtc { 

}
```

The thing is that your scoped styles get compiled to

```
.daten[data-v-bla-bla]{
...
}

b[data-v-bla-bla]{
...
}

/* and .vtc-statistik with nested .vtc */
.vtc-statistik .vtc[data-v-bla-bla] {
...
}
```

in order to work the way you expect it to work it should get compiled to

```css
/* */
.vtc-statistik[data-v-bla-bla] .vtc{
...
}
```

where `data-v-bla-bla` is a unique id of your component.

Btw. Nested styles are not part of CSS specifications. You should use SCSS / PostCSS / Less to process them.

Comment: Thanks a lot already figured out that it works in SCSS didn't know about this technology.